# Expecting errors when assigning to $_SESSION without starting a session in PHP

Tags: php, session

I'm not calling `session_start()` and php.ini has `session.auto_start = 0`.

I can still assign variables to the scope without any errors? No cookie is set but the scope is still available throughout the page. Should PHP raise an error if I haven't started the session?

Comment: If you don't want to have other devs "direct" access to `$_SESSION` then you need to overload it with a class that implements `ArrayAccess` in which you make it throw an exception on write access as long as the session has not been started yet. Additionally you can verify that only "variables" are set which names are under your control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [$_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) is a superglobal, it's available in all scopes at all times.

Just because the session itself hasn't been initialized with the browser, that doesn't mean that this variable doesn't exist.  It's still there waiting to be used, and you're free to store to it at any time, but my understanding is that it will be wiped out if you write to it, **then** initialize the session.

## edit:

This code results in `two => Second` as expected.

```
<?php
        $_SESSION['test'] = "string";
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['two'] = "Second";

        foreach( $_SESSION as $key => $val )
        {
                print $key . " => " . $val;
                print "<br />";
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can assign to `$argc` and `$argv` although they are defined in CLI only; you can assign to `$_FILES`, to `$_SERVER` and even to `$GLOBALS`. All of those are **variables**, and PHP won't stop you to assign new value. And since it is a dynamic language and variable declaration is not needed, it won't stop you from initializing the variable. However if you try to get the value of `$_SESSION` before you've assigned anything to it, and before calling `session_start`, it will give you `'undefined variable' notice`.

Answer (score 0):

The $_SESSION superglobal is always available, regardless of whether you started a session or not. The only difference is that if you never do a `session_start()` in your code, or don't have sessions auto-starting via .ini settings, anything you put into $_SESSION will be lost when the script exits.

The same applies to all the superglobals - they're always available. There's a $_POST array, even if the script was invoked via a GET query, and there's a $_COOKIE array, even if you invoke the script on the command line with no webserver in sight.